# Как вывести char массив в строке через функцию WriteLine?

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь разбить строку на четыре 16-ричных числа и вывести их в на консоль.

И столкнулся с проблемой как вывести из консоли ( функцией `Console.WriteLine`) **char[]** массив.

вот программа :

```
using System;
using System.Text;

// логарифм: 
// 1. считываем строку +
// 2. убираем все пробелы и запятые + 
// 3. разбиваем на строки с количеством символов в 4 числа

namespace trimtram
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Тестовая прога.");
            string stroka = Console.ReadLine(); // 1

            stroka = stroka.Replace(" ", "");          // 2
            stroka = stroka.Replace(",", "");          // 2
            stroka = stroka.Replace(".", "");          // 2

            //int t_per = 0; int t_per1 =0;
            int t_per_str = stroka.Length/4;   
            Console.WriteLine("stroka.Length ={0} ,t_per_str = {1}.", stroka.Length, t_per_str);

            Console.WriteLine(stroka);

            char[] stroka_t = new char[t_per_str];
            int t_per = 0; 
            for (int i =0; i<stroka.Length; i++)
            { 
                stroka_t[t_per] = stroka[i];
        t_per = t_per+1;
                if (t_per == 4)
                { Console.WriteLine("stroka_t ={0}",stroka_t.ToString()); t_per=0; }
                //{ Console.WriteLine("stroka_t =" + stroka_t.ToString()); t_per = 0; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Вот вывод :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn7.cs 
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mono tehn7.exe 
Тестовая прога.
0xa1 0x01 0x02 0x00 
stroka.Length =16 ,t_per_str = 4.
0xa10x010x020x00
stroka_t =System.Char[]
stroka_t =System.Char[]
stroka_t =System.Char[]
stroka_t =System.Char[]
```

Также пробовал так :

```
...
{ Console.WriteLine("stroka_t =" + stroka_t.ToString()); t_per = 0; }
...
```

Результат такой :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn7.cs 
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mono tehn7.exe 
Тестовая прога.
0xa1 0x01 0x02 0x00
stroka.Length =16 ,t_per_str = 4.
0xa10x010x020x00
stroka_t =System.Char[]
stroka_t =System.Char[]
stroka_t =System.Char[]
stroka_t =System.Char[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Моя ошибка была в том что я комбинировал `char[]` со строковым литералом.

`Console.WriteLine("stroka_t="+stroka_t.ToString());`

Метод `.ToString()` в `char[]` возвращает его тип, а не значение.

---

Надо было изменить строку так :

```
{ Console.WriteLine("stroka_t ={0}", new string(stroka_t)); t_per = 0; }
```

либо

```
Console.WriteLine(stroka_t);
```

В этом случае `Console.WriteLine(stroka_t);` интерфейс Console делает перегрузку и оборачивает массив **char[]** в строку.

Вот исправленная программа :

```
using System;
using System.Text;

// логарифм: 
// 1. считываем строку +
// 2. убираем все пробелы и запятые + 
// 3. разбиваем на строки с количеством символов в 4 числа +

namespace trimtram
{ 
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Тестовая прога.");
            string stroka = Console.ReadLine(); // 1

            stroka = stroka.Replace(" ", "");          // 2
            stroka = stroka.Replace(",", "");          // 2
            stroka = stroka.Replace(".", "");          // 2

            // 3 ---
            int t_per_str = stroka.Length/4;   
            Console.WriteLine("stroka.Length ={0} ,t_per_str = {1}.", stroka.Length, t_per_str);

            Console.WriteLine(stroka);

            char[] stroka_t = new char[t_per_str];
            int t_per = 0; 
            for (int i =0; i<stroka.Length; i++)
            { 
                stroka_t[t_per] = stroka[i];
        t_per = t_per+1;
                if (t_per == 4)
                { Console.WriteLine("stroka_t ={0}", new string(stroka_t)); t_per = 0; }
            }
            // ---
        }
    }
}
```

Вот вывод :

```
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mcs tehn7.cs 
comp@comp0:~/Qt_project/TCP_IP$ mono tehn7.exe 
Тестовая прога.
0xa1 0x01 0x02 0x00
stroka.Length =16 ,t_per_str = 4.
0xa10x010x020x00
stroka_t =0xa1
stroka_t =0x01
stroka_t =0x02
stroka_t =0x00
```

---

Также замечу что очень интересно себя ведет `WriteLine` :3